# Binary representation of Pascal's triangle

Tags: javascript

I recently learnt about the binary representation of Pascal's triangle. Here is what it looks like[image]
I am a java learner. Is there a way for me to find the java source code to graph this binary representation?

Comment: This site is more about description of techniques and algorithms for computer graphics - not about where to find source code. However, if you were able to give more clues about what you want maybe someone could help.

Comment: If it's about the visualization, you could use a simple image format such as pgm for example to display the results (Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format)

Comment: @Larry 
but how is the construction of those bugs

Comment: @ x-rw: Here is link that explains how these bugs are constructed. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982466/binary-representation-of-pascals-triangle